# Are background mode location and fetch called even after the device restarted in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, fetch

I'm writing an application that uses the fetch and location background mode. I'm interested in knowing if these two event they can start the application even after a reboot in iOS7 and iOS6.

Comment: Have you tried testing it?

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to answer myself (don't know if it could be useful to someone else), but please correct me if I say wrong. After several tests I've seen that on **iOS7, even after a reboot the events are called** (like if no reboot happened). On iOS6 this not happens.

Answer (score 0):

The location background mode can restart the app in iOS 6 and iOS 7. In iOS 7 this will work unless the user force quit the app.

The fetch mode will only work for iOS 7. It isn't supported in iOS 6.